# Google VR Android SDK VrPanoramaView Can't rotate around Pitch and Roll axes

Tags: android, android-studio, rotation, virtual-reality, google-vr

I am using the VrPanoramaView widget from Google VR Android SDK. I built the SimplePanoView sample that came along with the SDK and tried it out on my device but I can only rotate along the yaw axis.

There are also random instances when it rotates too slowly, when that happens, I tilt my phone to landscape to fix it. But, even then, I still can't rotate along the roll and pitch axes no matter how hard I swipe or rotate the phone.

I tried the andes image and even the rendered files in the SDK but the problem remains.

I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!